# Is it possible to know the amount of rotation one made so far in three.js?

Tags: rotation, three.js

I've built a scene with a cube and a camera placed in the center of the cube. I am able to rotate the cube. Ideally I would like to limit to rotation to horizontal.

Is there any way to count the amount of rotation? For example, being able to know at every amount that I rotated 30 radians in a direction, and if I rotate backgword the amount gets updated accordingly.

Comment: Not really, 30 radians are indistinguishable from 30-8pi ~ 4.867 radians. But within 2pi range, mesh.position.y should be fine.

Comment: You mean mesh.rotation.y

Comment: Mh, in other words: is there any way to tell if we're facing a face of a cube or another?

Comment: All objects have a rotation attribute on them. If you want to know the rotation around the vertical axis, just use object.rotation.y and that gives you the amount of rotation in radians. However I think you need to rephrase your question to what you really want.